# Visual Studio Code context menu changes after update and functions are missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using Visual Studio Code for some time and love it. However, recently I updated it on two separate Windows PCs (one is Windows 10, the other Windows 7), and now I have the same problem on both. I am now running version 1.14.1 of VS Code.

Previously, when I right-clicked in my html, JavaScript, or other files, I got a number of functions in the context menu, such as 'Format Code', 'Go to Definition', 'Find All References', 'Peek Definition', etc. Now almost all of these options are missing from all my file types, except html. Furthermore, if I try the keyboard shortcut to format code (Shift-Ctrl-F), it doesn't work.

The only options I still have in the context menu are 'Change all occurrences', 'cut copy paste', 'Command Palette'.

I've tried reinstalling VS Code, but with no luck.

Comment: I've checked more closely, and it seems html files work as expected, as do css files and json. It seems it's only Javascript that don't. In the settings, "javascript.format.enable" is set to true, but it is listed under a Typescript heading.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated to the most recent version of VS Code (1.14.2), and the context menu is back to normal. Perhaps it was a bug? I didn't see it listed in the issues, but I may have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me on Ubuntu 21.10 and the latest VS Code (1.66.2). I fixed it by reinstalling the Python extension.